# ACTION_MOVE interferes with ACTION_DOWN

Tags: android

I have a view set on touch, it has three MotionEvents (down,  move,  up).

I return true in (down and move )and false for up.

I know that Action down is triggered when we touch the view and Action move is when we move our finger on screen and Action up is when we lose contact with screen.

The problem: is that when I touch the view only without moving my finger on screen both Action down and Move are triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You are moving it.  If you finger moves by even 1 pixel, it counts as a move.  Its pretty much physically impossible to not move your finger by at least one pixel when pressing down-  and even if you could you'd be hit by sensor inaccuracy.  To get around that, you need to ignore any moves smaller than a threshold size.

Comment: yes I understand exactly what you said and its true , but can you give me any example just for explanation please.

Comment: how can I make a threshold limit for move.

Comment: Store the location where the down occurred.  In a move, check what the difference between the new x/y and the original ones were.  If neither are big enough (big enough is something you can play with, start with 10 pixels or so) just ignore the event.

Comment: I tried and I cant figure out how to use your solution , can you please provide a simple code on what should I write in action down and action move.